# How to get attribute title form different store view

Tags: attributes, magento-1, multistore, frontend

I have one attribute for two different product types. That attribute shoudl call 'x' in product type 1 and 'y' in product type 2. I created two different store views so i can name my attribute in two ways. Now how i can display this two different names. Now i'm getting attribute name by

```
   attr = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attrCode);

   $attr->getData('frontend_label')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getStoreLabel` method.

This will return you label for current store view

```
$attr->getStoreLabel();
```

Or you can pass as parameter store id to get some specific label

```
$attr->getStoreLabel($storeId);
```

For details look into `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute::getStoreLabel()`